Do I need to display constants in the step count method
I tried looking this up before coming here but I couldn't find any resources. If there is a post that already exists that can explain this please let me know so I can close this one.
I am creating some runtime analytics for a paper I'm submitting. I've noticed quite a few of the functions have many constant lines. Since I plan to drop these for the big O notation would it be improper to exclude them from the analysis to increase the readability or is there some space saving method to convey there are multiple constants in this function?
Nonsense pseudocode Example:
void counter( vector<string> n) {
    int count_names = 0
    int count_characters = 0
    For each name in n
        count_names++
            For each character in name
                count_characters++
    

Example of step count:



Code
line cost
# of executes
Total




int count_names = 0
1
1
1


int count_characters = 0
1
1
1


For each name in n
1
n
n


count_names++
1
n
n


For each character in name
1
n * n
n^2


count_characters++
1
n * n
n^2




Total cost
2n^2 + 2n + 2




Runtime
O(n^2)



Or can I reduce with something like this:



Code
line cost
# of executes
Total




Setup constants
2
1
2


For each name in n
1
n
n


count_names++
1
n
n


For each character in name
1
n * n
n^2


count_characters++
1
n * n
n^2




Total cost
2n^2 + 2n + 2




Runtime
O(n^2)



While it doesn't seem like a lot on this example it could save me a lot of space. Is this improper of me to do? Thanks for your input!

Since you are finally going to present an asymptototic bound, you can simplify things a bit. Typically, we assume all basic operations are executed within some constant amount of time and simply count the total number of such basic operations. In most cases, we focus only on the dominant part of the code, such as loops or recursive calls.
